# Getting GeoJSON data in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to collect geojson data and use it. I need to define a boundary box for my working area. This function gives correct results for line and polygon. But when I use point data it gets stuck.

```js
L.Control.fileLayerLoad({
    fitBounds: true,
    layerOptions: {
        style: style,
        pointToLayer:function (data, latlng) {debugger;
            return L.circleMarker(
            latlng,
            { style: style }
            );
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            console.log("FEATURE",feature,"LAYER",layer);
            geojsonLayer = layer // 
        }
    }

}).addTo(map);
```

```js
function geojsonLayerBounds(map, geojson){
 var rectangle = new L.Rectangle(geojson.getBounds());
 map.addLayer(rectangle);
}
```

Comment: what gets stuck? what is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood  correctly you need to to get bounds of points or to zoom in on it. To do that, you can use function map.flyTo() which is available in Leaflet 1.x.x 
I added some example below, hope it helps

Here is reference to that function with some example code:

```
flyTo(<LatLng> latlng, <Number> zoom?, <Zoom/pan options> options?)
flyTo([46.163613, 46.163613], 12)
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-flyto

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([46.163613, 15.750947], 14);
 mapLink =
     '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
 L.tileLayer(
     'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
         attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
         maxZoom: 18,
     }).addTo(map);


 var work = {
     lat: 46.165932,
     lng: 15.865914,
     zoom: 17
 };

 L.easyButton('fa-globe', function(btn, map) {
     map.flyTo([work.lat, work.lng], work.zoom);
 }, 'Fly to work').addTo(map);

 var home = {
     lat: 46.163613,
     lng: 15.750947,
     zoom: 13
 };

 L.easyButton('fa-home', function(btn, map) {
     map.flyTo([home.lat, home.lng], home.zoom);
 }, 'Please come home').addTo(map)
```

```css
#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <title>Custom Icons Tutorial - Leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-easybutton@2.0.0/src/easy-button.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-easybutton@2.0.0/src/easy-button.js"> </script>
               
</head>

<body>

  <div id='map'></div>

</body>

</html>
```